# RVM Path Issues, Need to Run `rvm use` Every Session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Eventually trying to get a staging server running on a mac using Capistrano. Right now I'm just trying to get the environment setup correctly at login.

```
$bundle show rails
-bash: bundle: command not found
$ rvm use 1.9.3
Using /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551
$ bundle show rails
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/gems/rails-3.1.10
```

Here's the output of `gem environment`

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 551) [x86_64-darwin14.5.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-14
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm@global/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm/bin
     - /Users/me/.rvm/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Here's `~/.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Nothing is in `~/.profile`.

Not sure what's normal for `rvm list` but I feel like the 2 installations of 1.9.3 could be an issue.

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.0.0-p643 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

**Update:** Definitely something up with the installation of 1.9.3. Uninstalled both 1.9.3-p551 and 1.9.3-p551-rvm and reinstalled 1.9.3-p551. Now when cd'ing in the dir, it says:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551-rvm'
```

Not sure why it's insisting on `-rvm` at the end. My `.ruby-version` just has `rvm 1.9.3-p551`.

**Another update:** There was no reason for me to stick with 1.9.3 so I've moved to 2.0.0. There seems to be some kind of bug with rvm expecting `-rvm` on the end for 1.9.3. Still need to get my paths rvm paths figured out. The path *to* RVM is fine. It seems to be a global issue. A directory that is working fine has `which bundle` return `/Users/joshuamark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/bundle`. The directory that doesn't work returns `/Users/joshuamark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/bundle` after using `rvm use`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a fresh bash session, I ran `gem install bundler` then `bundle` in the broken directory. Once that was finished, `gem env` had the right paths and a new session found the `bundle` command.

I still find it very odd that `rvm use` pointed to the default rvm environment instead of the namespaced one in the app (via `.ruby-gemset`). It seems installing bundler has something to do with setting the gem env for rvm. I'd appreciate some insight there if someone has it.